# Export user's passwords from one sites to another

Tags: 7, users, migrations, importing-exporting

I queried users table from an old site and saved those users in a new site, excluding passwords (every user has default 'password' password). Now I'd like to get hashed passwords from the old site and copy them to the new site's users table. Both sites are Drupal 7 and have the same hash salt string in settings.php.

I noticed all users with the same password 'password' have different hashed passwords. Therefore I am wondering, will be users able to log in to the new site with their original passwords after replacing current hashed 'password' password with the original hashed passwords from the old site?

Comment: yes users will be able to login.